# Console output with `catkin make_tests` for ROS1

Tags: ros, logging, unit-testing

I'm running some C++ unit tests in CI with

```
catkin run_tests my_pkg
```

I wanted to collect the unit tests' output (INFO or higher), similar to when we run

```
rostest my_pkg my_test.test --text
```

I've tried looking into XML files, but they don't have console output:

```
[ROSTEST]Running test [test_battery_exchange]
&amp;#x001B;[1mROS_MASTER_URI=http://annie:37713/&amp;#x001B;[0m
&amp;#x001B;[1msetting /run_id to 8b27aca8-e077-11ee-b501-dc214839b96c&amp;#x001B;[0m
[ROSTEST]running test test_battery_exchange
&amp;#x001B;[1mprocess[test_battery_exchange-1]: started with pid [288742]&amp;#x001B;[0m
&amp;#x001B;[1m[test_battery_exchange-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/rr/.ros/log/8b27aca8-e077-11ee-b501-dc214839b96c/test_battery_exchange-1*.log&amp;#x001B;[0m
[ROSTEST]test [test_battery_exchange] finished
```

That log file, though, `/home/rr/.ros/log/8b27aca8-e077-11ee-b501-dc214839b96c/test_battery_exchange-1-stdout.log`, does contain what I want:

```
[ INFO] [1710251488.686978957] [/test_battery_exchange ros.oks_alica.queryForBEC vector<oks_alica::Location> oks_alica::BatteryHandler::queryForBEC 91]: Discovered BEC at x: 1 y: 1 floor: 2
[ INFO] [1710251488.686988677] [/test_battery_exchange ros.oks_alica QueryForBEC::run 32]: Found Battery Exchange location at x: 5 y: 5 floor: 2
```

I'm not sure how I'd use `catkin_test_results` to capture these, it just shows me a summary of the test. I have also tried directly outputting to console, but no luck there either.